# Error: Response and predictor must be vectors of the same length

Tags: r, response, proc

I'm getting following error, how to fix it?

```
install.packages("pROC")
library(pROC)
lr_predict <- predict(lg_model,train_data, probability =TRUE)
auc_gbm = roc(test_data$Class,lr.predict,plot = TRUE, col = "blue")
```

> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
>   Error in roc.default(test_data$Class, lr.predict, plot = TRUE, col = "blue") :
>       Response and predictor must be vectors of the same length.

Comment: It literally means that your response and predictors have different lengths. That's all I can say in the absence of any data.

Comment: You probably want to change the train_data to test_data in predict(lg_model,train_data, probability =TRUE).

Answer (score 1):

Following the response of @Shirin Yavari, you could use a code like that:

```
lr_predict <- predict(lg_model, test_data, probability =TRUE)
auc_gbm = roc(test_data$Class, lr.predict, plot = TRUE, col = "blue")
```